# How to read html reports from AWS codeBuild?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

In my `buildspec.yml` file I add this:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: latest
    commands:
      - ...
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - ...
  build:
    commands:
      - ...

reports:
  NoraUIReports:
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'target/reports'
```

In `target/reports/html` I have `index.html`, `style.css`, `report.js`, `jquery-1.8.2.min.js`, `...`

I try change to:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: target/reports
```

I find all my files on S3 but all files are zipped again.

My **workaround** is remove `artifacts` part and add aws command line `aws s3 sync target/reports s3://$ACCOUNT_ID-$STACK_NAME-...` in `post_build` part

Comment: I have a similar requirement but I couldn't make out from your workaround, can you please specify with more details?

My requirement:
In code build I generate a html report and now I wanted to read the html report or is it possible to store in codebuild report? please suggest